# SSIS: Concatenate all emails in SSIS job to just one email?

Tags: t-sql, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

The screenshot below is a sample SSIS project that does lots of stuff and sends several emails.

For example, there are two tasks that download data. There are 5 other tasks that generate data for reports. There are also several tasks that email users with report links and CSV links.

After all of that is executed, I need to create one email that will include the name of each task and if the task executed successfully or if it failed. The email will also include the links that are sent in the job.

The body of the email would look something like this:

- Generate totals for sales data: **Success**
- Generate totals for client data: **Fail**
- Download sales data: **Success**
- Download invoice data: **Fail**
- Process and generate CSV: Fail Generate reports used Finance: **Success**
- Email Report link to users: **http://company.com/MyReport.html**
- Email finance link for CSV: **http://10.40.230.320/Myfile.csv**

I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish this. I was considering using a tsql table that would be updated after every task completes, but I'm not sure if this is the best way. I was also considering using an SSIS variable, but the last time I did use them many, many years ago, it wasn't a positive experience.

[image]

Comment: If anything fails it will never get to the final step. Put everything into a Sequence container except the final email. and link on Completion (Success or failure). I would have a variable for each step defaulted to false and then mark it true after it completes. And then use those variables to compile your final email. I see you are using script tasks to send email so I figure you know how to do this.

Comment: In a Sequence container the process flow will continue even if a step failed?

Comment: that is an option. it is actually an option for every connection in the control flow.

Comment: Also, your items might not be connected. If things can be run independently then remove the connections. This will help in 2 ways. Your independent processes can run asynchronously (faster) and processes independent of a failed process have a chance to run.

Comment: Finally, if several steps need to complete before another step runs and they are unconnected, then put those inside a sequence container (inside the overall sequence container defined above)